# LxNotificationService service not working in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, lumx

I have recently started working with AngularJS and Lumx. I have tried adding the notifications which can be found under int the 'notification' tab on the site. [Link is here](http://ui.lumapps.com/services/notifications).

Anywho's, the error I get is

> "Error: LxNotificationService is not defined"

So I add it to my list of services in the controller.

Below is my app.js file

```
var testing = angular.module('testing', []);
```

testing.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope){

```
$scope.notify = function(type)
{
    if (type === 'simple')
    {
        LxNotificationService.notify('Lorem Ipsum');
    }
    else if (type === 'sticky')
    {
        LxNotificationService.notify('Lorem Ipsum', undefined, true);
    }
    else if (type === 'icon')
    {
        LxNotificationService.notify('Lorem Ipsum', 'android');
    }
    else if (type === 'color')
    {
        LxNotificationService.notify('Lorem Ipsum', undefined, false, 'grey');
    }
    else if (type === 'info')
    {
        LxNotificationService.info('Lorem Ipsum');
    }
    else if (type === 'success')
    {
        LxNotificationService.success('Lorem Ipsum');
    }
    else if (type === 'warning')
    {
        LxNotificationService.warning('Lorem Ipsum');
    }
    else if (type === 'error')
    {
        LxNotificationService.error('Lorem Ipsum');
    }
};
```

});

Everything on the html page is working fine, I reckon I'm just not calling the service correctly. Can anyone assist please?

P.S.

Below is a list of all my script files.

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/velocity/velocity.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lumx/dist/lumx.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance, Niall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% as I am new to LumX but it looks like you are missing a dependency of the LumX module

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['lumx']);
```

Barry

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to specify the `lumx` module dependency when defining your `testing` module :

`angular.module('testing', ['lumx']);`

And also you forgot to inject the `LxNotificationService` in your controller :

```
angular.module('testing').controller('mainCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'LxNotificationService',
function ($scope, LxNotificationService) {
  ... your code here ...
}
```